# moving disks around on a 3ware raid controller , using tw_cli

Tags: hardware-raid, 3ware

I have a raid controller (9650SE-4LPML)
I am unluckily in a rather crappy situation:

```
Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-1    OK             -       -       -       139.688   Ri     ON
u1    RAID-1    DEGRADED       -       -       -       1862.63   Ri     ON
u2    RAID-1    INOPERABLE     -       -       -       1862.63   Ri     ON

VPort Status         Unit Size      Type  Phy Encl-Slot    Model
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p0    OK             u0   139.73 GB SATA  0   -            WDC WD1500HLFS-01G6
p1    OK             u0   139.73 GB SATA  1   -            WDC WD1500HLFS-01G6
p2    OK             u1   1.82 TB   SATA  2   -            WDC WD20EARS-00MVWB0
p3    OK             u2   1.82 TB   SATA  3   -            WDC WD20EARS-00MVWB0
```

Focusing on units `u1` & `u2`, and disks `p2` & `p3`:

Initially there was only `u1` (no `u2`) configured in raid-1 with disks `p2` & `p3`. 
Now as you see this "monster" has been created. also `p2`

My question is, how to I return `p3` in u1?

On occasions `p2` will return in `dmesg`

```
3w-9xxx: scsi0: AEN: ERROR (0x04:0x0009): Drive timeout detected:port=2.
```

and `p3`:

```
3w-9xxx: scsi0: AEN: WARNING (0x04:0x000F): SMART threshold exceeded:port=3.
```

but later these messages vanish:S

So not too great of a situation and I know I have to change disks, but what is worse is to have 2 separate disks in 2 separate 'units'. I'd much rather prefer to have them together.
So what commands do I need to bring `p3` back into `u1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, I think you already find your answer.
It seems that your p3 has already been used on a 3ware controller. That's why you get u2 when you have inserted p3.

You should delete u2 and then you will be able to add p3 in u1.

Be careful, p3 has already sent SMART errors, you should not use it.